# Breakpoints for Flutter are broken

Tags: flutter-web, flutter-debug, flutter-devtools

I've been trying to get breakpoints to function in VS Code. I'm on the latest version of the stable channel of Flutter, as well as VS Code and the extensions for Dart and Flutter.

I know this question has been asked and answered several times, but all those answers have just been voodoo fixes. Thus I ask again, as none worked for me.

Yes I'm doing F5 and not Ctrl+F5. Yes I tried reinstalling the extensions and VS Code and flutter and Windows.

Yes the breakpoints still become unverified as soon as VS Code connects to chrome. My project is web-only.

I know this is an unfixable issue and that even though its been fixed multiple times on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, currently its a bug. Follow [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/webdev/issues/1271) for updates.